# Why is my method not seeing null Object

Tags: java

I seem not to understand this.

```
public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object obj = null;
        myMethod(obj);
    }

    public static void myMethod(Object... objArr) {
        if(objArr != null) {
            System.out.println("I am not null");
        }
    }
}
```

To my surprise, `I am not null` is printed on the console. Why is `myMethod` not seeing the passed `obj` parameter as null.

Comment: `objArray` isn't null because it's an array with a single element: `null`.

Comment: Because Object obj is the first element of your array. Try printing the first element of objArr.

Comment: Check for objArr[0] == null

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The method signature `Object... objArr` introduces a "varargs" variable.  Every argument passed in a call to such a method is given its own slot in an array of that name.

Therefore, when you pass one `null`, you get an array `objArr` of length 1, whose only element is `null`.  The array itself isn't null, the element is.

The [JLS, Section 8.4.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.1) calls these "variable arity parameters":

> The last formal parameter of a method or constructor is special: it
>   may be a variable arity parameter, indicated by an ellipsis following
>   the type.

and

> Invocations of a variable arity method may contain more actual
>   argument expressions than formal parameters. All the actual argument
>   expressions that do not correspond to the formal parameters preceding
>   the variable arity parameter will be evaluated and **the results stored
>   into an array** that will be passed to the method invocation
>   (§15.12.4.2).

(emphasis mine)

Answer (score 6):

A method with a parameter list like `Object... objArr` takes an array parameter.  When you call it from `main`, the parameter is an array with one element.  The one element, `objArr[0]`, will be null.  But the array itself is not null.

In fact, even if you call the method with no arguments, i.e. `myMethod()`, the array still isn't null.  It will be an array of length 0.

Answer (score 0):

The array `objArr` will not be null, be you are passing one argument `obj` from `main` when calling this function. `obj` is null, but the array contains this null element, which means the array has a size of 1, and is not null.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(objArr != null)
        {
            System.out.println("I am not null because I am an ARRAY object");
            System.out.println("I have " + objArr.length + " element(s)");
        }

        if(objArr[0] == null)
        {
            System.out.println("NULL");
        }
```

**OUTPUT ->**

```
  I am not null because I am an ARRAY object
  I have 1 element(s)
  NULL
```

**objArr** behaves like **args** in main(String[] **args**)
and if u try objArr[1] it will throw an exception meaning objArr is almost an array